# Windows 10 Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to use the result of a formula in a calculation for another cell. 
First I used the IF function to calculate the 1st cells’ value

```
=IF(F5=LUL!$F$4, LUL!G4, IF(F5<=LUL!$F$5, LUL!$G$5, IF(F5<=LUL!$F$6, LUL!$G$6, IF(F5<=LUL!$F$7, LUL!$G$7, IF(F5>LUL!$F$8, LUL!$G$8)))))
```

When I use the result of this in a new calculation (MIN in this case) I only get a value of '0'.

The results of the 1st formula can only be £220.00, £260.00, £320.00 & £400.00.

The formula that I’m trying to use in a different sheet of the same work book is this:

```
=MIN('Venues V''s OP''s'!E5,'Venues V''s OP''s'!I5,'Venues V''s OP''s'!K5,'Venues V''s OP''s'!M5,'Venues V''s OP''s'!O5,'Venues V''s OP''s'!Q5,'Venues V''s OP''s'!S5)
```

The results are 0